# Access a Nested array from MongoDB collection

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, maps

Been racking my brains for a few days, and not getting any further forward.

I have a project using a MERN stack, and I'm trying to access a nested array from my database.

This is what my data structure looks like:

```
const Products = [
    {
        name: 'Air Zoom Pegasus 37',
        brand: 'Nike',
        category: 'running',
        material: 'Textile & Synthetic Upper/Synthetic sole',
        description: 'Hit a new PB in these mens Air Zoom Pegasus 37 trainers from Nike. In an Off Noir colourway with hits of Blue Fury and Bright Crimson, these runners have lightweight mesh upper for a breathable feel. They feature a secure lace up fastening and are sat on a soft foam midsole for long-lasting cushioning and maximum responsiveness. With Nikes Air Zoom unit at the forefront for a smooth ride, these trainers are finished with a grippy rubber tread and the iconic Swoosh logo to the sidewalls.',
        price: 105,
        sizes: [
            { size: '6', countInStock: 10 },
            { size: '7', countInStock: 10 },
            { size: '8', countInStock: 10 },
            { size: '9', countInStock: 10 },
            { size: '10', countInStock: 10 },
            { size: '11', countInStock: 10 },
            { size: '12', countInStock: 10 }
        ],

        image1: '/images/nike_pegasus37_1.jpeg',

        image2: '/images/nike_pegasus37_2.jpeg',

        image3: '/images/nike_pegasus37_3.jpeg',

        image4: '/images/nike_pegasus37_4.jpeg',

        image5: '/images/nike_pegasus37_5.jpeg',

        image6: '/images/nike_pegasus37_6.jpeg',

        rating: 0,
        numReviews: 0,
        tags: 'nike, adidas, running, trainers, 5k, new, style',
    },
]
```

I can't seem to access the nested objects in the 'Sizes' array. All the properties are returned in the state using Redux and I can see that the data payload returns all items from this BSON list in my Redux Devtools on Chrome.

I'm retrieving this data using Axios from a MongoDB collection, and using Redux to manage my state using dispatch and selector. Everything else works. I can fetch every other piece of information so I know it's not a back end problem, but I just can't seem to figure out how to map that array out.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Liam.

Comment: It seems like you are missing something, your `Products` array doesn't have a closing `]` and also it has object properties directly in the array. Please fix it.

Comment: Sorry it was the way I copied it across to here. I only pasted one product from my file, as it is pretty long and forgot to put the closing array bracket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To map an array in react you can do it like this

```
Component start......

    return {
        <div>
            {
                // First map over your Products
                // note the ? is there to prevent it from crashing if Products is not defined
                Products?.map(product => {
                   return <>
                        <p>{product.name}</p>
 
                        //then map over this products sizes
                        <div>
                             
                             {product?.sizes.map(size => {
                                 return <p>{size.size} - {size.countInStock}</p>
                             })}
                        </div>
                    </>
                })
            }
        </div>
    }
```